# Using $graphLookup with a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find the ancestors of a given child. At some point, that child's ancestors last name changed. I want to find the last parent of this child with a given last name. For example:

```
{
    "_id":1,
    "parent":null
    "first":"Bob",
    "last":"Sagget"
},
{
    "_id":2,
    "parent":1,
    "first":"Jane",
    "last":"Dor"
},
{
    "_id":3,
    "parent":2,
    "first":"Crane",
    "last":"Dor"
},
{
    "_id":4,
    "parent":3,
    "first":"Ho",
    "last":"Dor"
},
{
    "_id":5,
    "parent":4,
    "first":"Mor",
    "last":"Dor"
}
```

I want to query for `_id` **5** and get the ancestors with the last name **Dor**. There will be other people with the name Dor in this database that I don't want to see, so I can't just query for last name of "Dor".

Here is my current aggregation query - this is giving me every ancestor all the way to `_id` of 1. How can I stop at `_id` of 2?:

```
db.PeopleDb.aggregate(
[
    {
        $graphLookup: {
                "from": "PeopleDb", 
                "startWith": "$parent", 
                "connectFromField": "parent", 
                "connectToField": "_id", 
                "as": "linearAncestors"
            }
        },
        {
        $match: {
        "_id":5
        }
    },
]);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic query you are looking for instead actually "starts" with the restriction on matching just the singular document with `_id: 5` and then performs the [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) in order to find the ancestors.

As for the "condition", there are some steps involved so it is best to walk through the whole process and understand what is happening:

```
db.PeopleDb.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": 5 } },
  { "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "PeopleDb",
    "startWith": "$parent",
    "connectFromField": "parent",
    "connectToField": "_id",
    "as": "people",
    "depthField": "depth"
  }}
])
```

This then returns all the recursive chain connecting the `parent` to the `_id`, noting also the "optional" `"depthField"` setting to include the actual "depth" of the match within the returned results:

```
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "parent" : 4,
    "first" : "Mor",
    "last" : "Dor",
    "people" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "parent" : null,
            "first" : "Bob",
            "last" : "Sagget",
            "depth" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "parent" : 1,
            "first" : "Jane",
            "last" : "Dor",
            "depth" : NumberLong(2)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "parent" : 2,
            "first" : "Crane",
            "last" : "Dor",
            "depth" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "parent" : 3,
            "first" : "Ho",
            "last" : "Dor",
            "depth" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    ]
}
```

So noting that `4` is returned since it is the parent of the initial document, then `3` for it's parent and then `2` as it's parent and so on.

You can restrict the "depth" of matching using the "optional" `"maxDepth"` parameter to the pipeline stage, or in the specific case of "excluding the ROOT" element you can use the `"restrictSearchWithMatch"` option to simply exclude results with a `null` parent:

```
db.PeopleDb.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": 5 } },
  { "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "PeopleDb",
    "startWith": "$parent",
    "connectFromField": "parent",
    "connectToField": "_id",
    "as": "people",
    "depthField": "depth",
    "restrictSearchWithMatch": { "parent": { "$ne": null } }
  }}
])
```

Which returns the same result, but excludes the "ROOT" document where the `"parent"` field is `null`:

```
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "parent" : 4,
    "first" : "Mor",
    "last" : "Dor",
    "people" : [
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "parent" : 1,
            "first" : "Jane",
            "last" : "Dor",
            "depth" : NumberLong(2)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "parent" : 2,
            "first" : "Crane",
            "last" : "Dor",
            "depth" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "parent" : 3,
            "first" : "Ho",
            "last" : "Dor",
            "depth" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    ]
}
```

And of course the same principle applies to your `"last"` condition which can match only documents where that condition was true. Here I'll show both conditions, but the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) is optional:

```
db.PeopleDb.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": 5 } },
  { "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "PeopleDb",
    "startWith": "$parent",
    "connectFromField": "parent",
    "connectToField": "_id",
    "as": "people",
    "depthField": "depth",
    "restrictSearchWithMatch": {
      "$or": [
        { "parent": { "$ne": null }},
        { "last": "Dor" }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

**Note** however that the `"restrictSearchWithMatch"` is a "recursive" condition, therefore if any "ancestor" in the chain does not meet the `"last"` condition then the chain is *broken* and further ancestors are not retrieved. In order to get "all the ancestors" yet only show those who have the matching `"last"` then you [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the resulting array content instead:

```
db.PeopleDb.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": 5 } },
  { "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "PeopleDb",
    "startWith": "$parent",
    "connectFromField": "parent",
    "connectToField": "_id",
    "as": "people",
    "depthField": "depth",
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "people": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$people",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.last", "Dor" ] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or in fact "dynamically" by comparing to the value of the initial matched document to which the "ancestors" are related to by using the field value expression instead of a hard coded value:

```
db.PeopleDb.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": 5 } },
  { "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "PeopleDb",
    "startWith": "$parent",
    "connectFromField": "parent",
    "connectToField": "_id",
    "as": "people",
    "depthField": "depth",
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "people": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$people",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.last", "$last" ] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

In this case it's the same `2,3,4` ancestors, but in the event that say ancestor `3` actually had a different value for `"last"` then using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) actually returns `2,4` whilst the `"restrictSearchWithMatch"` would only return `4` since the `3` would "break the chain". That's the main difference.

> **N.B** The one thing you cannot do of yet using [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) is that "field comparison expression" is not allowed. If you wanted something along those lines then you would do further manipulation with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and possibly other operations such as [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) if your actual intent was indeed to "break the chain" at the point where that "field comparison" was not met within a recursive search.

Comment: `restrictSearchWithMatch` was my answer. Thank you for taking the time to write this up.

Comment: Wow, this is a thorough, well-written answer. Thanks for explaining this!

Comment: This is a really nice answer. Thanks! Do you know if it's possible to use the `depthField` inside the `restrictSearchWithMatch` query? I need something like `restrictSearchWithMatch: { $or: [{ depth: 0, parentId: 'A' }, { depth: { $gt: 0 }, parentId: 'B' }] }`

Comment: Is it also possible to look into the "people" variable, I have data where I want to find out the relation among the objects and that can go to any depth but I want what ever we have already visited in previous cycle should not be iterate again?